# Keeping a long minitoc from starting on a new page

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, minitoc

Is there a way to force a long `\minitoc` to begin on the same page as the chapter title and split into the next page if it is too lengthy? As of now my only long `\minitoc` starts on a new page and the chapter page is all but empty.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Should one add a MWE even if the problem is clearly stated and a tad obvious? Just checking.

Comment: I tried to recreate your problem in a MWE, but my `minitoc` split nicely into the next page. So you need to construct a MWE yourself, because you're doing something that's not obvious.

Comment: okey, dokey. Thank you for the clarification!